# sed command to match a pattern and replace it

Tags: shell, sed

I want to use sed command to replace sensitive information in logs with `****`.
One of the log looks like:

```
"Log: abcservice : dataUsername generated is = QWE000387769@as.bbi.co\n","stream":"stdout""
```

The expected output I want is:

```
"Log: abcservice : dataUsername generated is = ******@as.bbi.co\n","stream":"stdout""
```

I tried:

```
sed 's#"dataUsername generated is [a-zA-ZO-9@.-]"#"dataUsername generated is = ******"#g"
```

How can I match the pattern "dataUsername generated is = QWE000387769@as.bbi.co" and replace it with "dataUsername generated is = ******@as.bbi.co\n"

Comment: I this really a programming question and not rather a general computing question about Linux?

Comment: I have now removed the linux tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(dataUsername generated is = )[^@]*/\1******/' input_file
"Log: abcservice : dataUsername generated is = ******@as.bbi.co\n","stream":"stdout""
```